# error on left join

Tags: magento2.4

I'm getting errors in Left join, below is my code.

```
$motorcyclebookFactory =  $this->motorcyclebookFactory->create()
                          ->getCollection()
                          ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $productCollectionData->getId());
                
$motorcyclebookFactory->getSelect()->joinLeft(
           'rider_detail as wrd',
           'wrd.booking_id = main_table.booking_id',
           ['booking_id', 'booking_series_id']
);
```

**Error is**

```
{
    "code": "500",
    "message": "SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'product_id' in where clause is ambiguous, query was: SELECT `main_table`.*, `wrd`.`booking_id`, `wrd`.`booking_series_id` FROM `motorcycle_book` AS `main_table`\n LEFT JOIN `rider_detail` AS `wrd` ON wrd.booking_id = main_table.booking_id WHERE (`product_id` = '16533') AND (start_date between '2022-10-15' and '2022-10-15' OR end_date between '2022-10-15' and '2022-10-15' OR start_date <= '2022-10-15' and end_date >= '2022-10-15' )",
    "data": null,
    "success": false
}
```

how can I fix this, please help me with this
thank you.

Comment: Do you tried to run query in phpmyadmin ? what was the result ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the `main_table` to the filter function:

```
$motorcyclebookFactory =  $this->motorcyclebookFactory->create()
                      ->getCollection()
                      ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.product_id', $productCollectionData->getId());
```